# How to access a website not using the port number?

Tags: server

So I am fairly new to node.js

I am running a node.js tutorial that includes accessing the code using the port# as such:  **http://192.168.1.150:8888**

The tutorial works fine, but how can I access the site without using the port#? 
I have never seen an active website URL before that has the port # in it.
I would rather see http://192.168.1.150 without the port# in the address bar after the site is accessed.

I am not running Apache or nginx.  The node.js tutorial creates the webserver.

Ideas?

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: Well you can create a portforwarding, you can use apache to proxypass you from port 80 to port 8888 there are different ways to do so. Also you should be able to configure your service to listen on port 80 instead of 8888, then you can use only the IP.

Comment: um.  . . .typically  web browsers automatically go to port 80. I'm  no web server expert but i think you'd  need some sort of port forwarding  to redirect  the browser from port 80 automatically to 8888

Answer (score 1):

There are default ports for most services.  For classic http, that would be port 80.  You can find a comprehensive list in `/etc/services`.  So, configure your web server to listen to port 80, and you won't need to specify it any more.

Do note, that ports below 1000, need root privilege.

---

Edit: I missed the fact that you run pure Node.js.  You can most likely configure it to listen to port 80 too, but you will run into the above privilege issue.  Most production sites will have a webserver like apache or ngnix who will forward the request from port 80, to localhost port 8888 for you.  You can obviously also do that on your development platform.  If you want to keep it lightweight, use lighttpd and set it as a reverse proxy.  (First solution coming to mind, there might be even easier ones)

Comment: Thanks jaw...I will try your suggestion about lighttpd, though one thing that might concern me is security as I have no experience with reverse proxy.

Comment: You're working on a private IP space, with probably a firewall in front.   Unless you configured your router in such a way that "The Internet" can access your machine at `192.168.1.150` on port 8888, I doubt you'll be much at risk.

Comment: Yes, I have a little lab set up using Virtual Box.  I was thinking more down the line if I develop my ideas into something I can put online...